# Clear and sendkeys using javascript selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have a question text field. When I click on it `display:none` for h3 appears and for input tag dissappears. Then I can clear field and enter new name.

```
<td style="width:92%;">
                                <h3 id="question_text_1846" onclick="return onClickQuestion(1846,'text');">test name</h3>
                                <input type="text" id="question_text_input_1846" onkeypress="return OnKeyPress(event, 1846,'text');" name="question_text_input_1846" onblur="return onBlurQuestion(1846,'text');" placeholder="Question Text" value="test" class="form-control myInput" style="display:none;" />
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $("#question_text_1846").html(unescape($("#question_text_1846").html()));
                                </script>
                            </td>
```

The question is how to set new name(clear field and sendkeys) through selenium and may be javascript manipulations. I tried to use several methods , but it doesn't work.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@id='question_text_"+ExtractQuestionTextInputID()+"']"));
        actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.perform();
        element.click();

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='question_text_input_"+ExtractQuestionTextInputID()+"']"));

        element.clear();
element.sendKeys("test_question_one");
```

And also with js

```
String qtid = "question_text_" + ExtractQuestionTextInputID();
        String qtiid = "question_text_input_" + ExtractQuestionTextInputID();
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById("+qtid+").setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')");
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById("+qtiid+").setAttribute('style', '')");
```

This is the method for extracting id from tag attribute

```
public String ExtractQuestionTextInputID(){
        String question_text_input_id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='New Question']")).getAttribute("id");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(question_text_input_id);
        String mid = new String();
        while(m.find()) {
            //System.out.println(m.group());
            mid = m.group();
        }
        return mid;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting wait between clicking and finding input element

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar yes I tried WebDriverWait(driver, 3), it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly but did you try setting attribute 'value' of the input to an empty string?

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar I would like to post this as a comment. But I can't because I need 50 reputation and I have 41.

Comment: js.executeScript("document.getElementById("+qtiid+").setAttribute('value', '')");
@BJNM do you mean this?

Comment: @ssdwer Exactly.